# Getting all combinations recursively [Python]

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, combinations

Consider a dictionary:

```
 {  "A": [ ["B"], ["C"] ],
    "B": [ ["D"], ["E"] ],
    "C": [ ["H"] ],
    "D":[["I"],["J"]]
 }
```

I want to find all the possible paths that lead to A that are not in the dictionary keys. For example

```
A = [ [B], [C] ]
```

we can expand that to

```
A = [ [B, D, I],[B, D, J], [B, E], [C, H] ]
```

I am trying to come up with a recursive solution but I can't get  anything to work fully. 
Any suggestions how to approach this problem?

Comment: " I am trying to come up with a recursive solution but I can't get anything to work fully". Pls post your 'non-working' code here. "Any suggestions how to approach this problem?" Recursion is definitely an approach (depth first search).

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the path with the following function ,But as you dont post your code and i dont know what you try by your self thus i dont know where you have problem and i couldn't explain any thing till you tell about your try and this code :

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start,path=[]):
       path=path+[start]
       if not graph.has_key(start):
          return [path]
       paths = []
       for nodes in graph[start]:
          for n in nodes :
             if n[0] not in path:
                  newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, n[0], path)
                  for newpath in newpaths:
                      paths.append(newpath)
       return paths

g={  "A": [ ["B"], ["C"] ],
    "B": [ ["D"], ["E"] ],
    "C": [ ["H"] ],
    "D":[["I"],["J"]]
 }
```

Demmo :

```
print find_all_paths(g,'A')
[['A', 'B', 'D', 'I'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'J'], ['A', 'B', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'H']]

print find_all_paths(g,'B')
[['B', 'D', 'I'], ['B', 'D', 'J'], ['B', 'E']]
```